# How to set a Matplotlib axis as a colormap

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I would like to have the axes of a plot as colormaps instead of a single color. Color bars are nice but not on this axis.

Here is an example:

[image]

Is there a way to obtain such axes using matplotlib?

Comment: yes - just put two colorbars on the axes where you want them using inset_axes.  https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/axes/colorbar_placement.html#using-inset-axes